# SwiftKeychainWrapper 3.0.1, Accessibility Options

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I was wondering if anyone could help with the Accessibility Options of SwiftKeychainWrapper 3.0.1?

I've installed the pod and imported SwiftKeychainWrapper.

If I use:

```
KeychainWrapper.standard.set(true, forKey: "SavePicture")
```

it works fine, but it I use:

`KeychainWrapper.standard.set(true, forKey: "SavePicture", withAccessibility: KeychainItemAccessibility.afterFirstUnloc`k)

the value never changes to true.

Am I missing something really obvious here? Many thanks for any suggestions:)

Comment: How do you test it ?, especially read part ("the value never changes to true.")

Comment: I have tested it by running it in the project first with: let bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(true, forKey: "SavePicture") then: print(bool) - which prints "true". Then using: let bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(true, forKey: "SavePicture", withAccessibility: KeychainItemAccessibility.afterFirstUnlock) then: print(bool) - which prints "false". So it works when I don't use the "withAccessiblitiy", but never when it is added. But I need it to work when then app is backgrounded so I need to withAccessibility to work:)

Comment: I mean do you have any background jobs ot it is user action, as from description it is designed to be used in background stuff "After the first unlock, the data remains accessible until the next restart. This is recommended for items that need to be accessed by background applications.".

Comment: Yes, it is a background job, not a user action. There is an in app purchase in the app which allows you to save the pictures sent to the user. When purchased, the keychain remembers the value and allows the user to save the picture when the app receives it in the background (or foreground). 

It is odd why keyChainWrapper works fine when “withAccessibility: .afterFirstUnlock” is removed, but when added (so the user can download the picture in the background) it will not change the Bool to True.

Comment: The only thing to my eyes you can do is to debug "open class KeychainWrapper"

Comment: I will attempt to do that, many thanks for the advice:)